# Cannot send the message using the server cox.net

Tags: macos, mail.app

I have two 2009 iMacs with OS X 10.9.2 and I am a Cox Communications subscriber. Both computers receive emails and can be used to delete and file them, but as of about three weeks ago neither will send emails. When I try, I receive this message:

> Cannot send the message using the server cox.net.

When I switch to Cox Mail, everything is fully functional, but because logging into that system is cumbersome and because I have four years of folders full of files in my Apple Mail, I prefer not to switch.

I have paid both iYogi (recommended by Apple) and Cox Tech Solutions (recommended by Cox) to correct the problem, but their fixes are always temporary. I understand that there might be a compatibility problem between Mavericks and iMap.

Can any of you recommend a course of action?

Comment: Yes there are some IMAP issues. Check first on the server site for IMAP settings, then check on your Mail.app settings.

Answer (score 1):

I have been having an issue with Gmail, as of late. It forgets the SMTP (send mail) password, then a week later the incoming password. I use two factor authentication and application passwords so resetting the passwords, while annoying only takes a minute or two.

All that by way of saying that you may be having a similar issue: Mail.app forgetting the password.

Change your email password then go into mail.app -> Preferences -> Accounts and change the Incoming Mail Server password. Then click on the Outgoing Mail Server (SMTP) drop down menu and select Edit SMTP server list. Click on the server for Cox and type in the new password there too. Click OK.

Now, BEFORE YOU CLOSE THE PREFERENCES WINDOW...

It seems that mail.app in Mavericks does not always save changes, when you change just the password. I have found that making a change to the Description (add a dash to the end of what you have there) will then prompt you to save when you close the preferences window.

If it DOESN'T ask you to save go back in and repeat the above and try changing another field (Description always works for me) and closing. You NEED to get the save dialog.

Now try to send some mail.

Failing that you may need to remove the mail preferences files from your ~/Library folder, there are at least a couple in different places. I will leave it to you to find them, delete them and re-add ALL your mail settings... sigh...