# Apple Mail using El Capitan

Tags: macos

I receive incoming emails   but cannot send out.  They stay in the 'Out' box.  In Mail Preferences   it says  'Outgoing Mail Server (SMTP)   -  in the slot is 'concordmedia.org.uk    I am using  IMAP system.

Comment: I have a feeling it's because your ISP may have switched off TLS1.0 support. El Cap Mail cannot do TLS1.2, so you'll have to try find a mail client that does. I'd check with your ISP to be certain.

Comment: Thanks  Tetsujin,  I will investigate that.  Eric

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  If you don’t get good answers, consider asking a very precise question by editing your body. Like “how can I find the support number of my mail vendor” or “is there a troubleshooting wizard” or “does mail log errors somewhere so I can find and correct this”. [ask] and [tour] are excellent guides if you need more help in phrasing a question that attracts good answers.

Comment: @Tetsujin This is _not_ true! Apple Mail (and Apple Transport Security in general) added TLS 1.2 in 10.9 Mavericks in 2013.

Comment: Google spits a whole slew of issues with El Cap & 1.2

Comment: Probably due to outdated cipher suites.

Comment: Try disconnecting from your mail account from System Prefs and reconnect. It worked for me on iPad, I was getting the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot to go on, but here are the steps I follow:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204075

Is there a guide from your organization that explains how to configure Apple Mail or even a configuration profile so you can [enter the settings perfectly without having to enter them manually](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/124427/5472)?

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is due to El Capitan having insufficient HTTPS support (likely outdated cipher suites), you can fix the problem by setting up a local proxy server and routing https traffic through that. https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/fixing-https-issues-on-old-versions-of-os-x.2281326/

This would be the first instance I'm aware of in which a server dropped support for all of El Capitan's cipher suites, but it's plausible, as it has happened on older versions of OS X.

Answer (score 0):

It is very unusual for an email server's SMTP address to use the same address as its parent website.  It is much more usual to use an address starting with `smtp`.

A DNS lookup for `smtp.concordmedia.org.uk` gives different result to `concordmedia.org.uk`, so I am confident that your issue is an incorrectly specified SMTP server.  Try `smtp.concordmedia.org.uk`.